# Can't call Swift function in another function

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I ama new to programming in XCode and wanted to reprogram a drag and drop game...the code so far looks as follows...however when I run it function "didMove" is not able to call function "setupDragLabel"....It walways opens the debugger....I have no idea what I am doing wrong ....Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated!!!

p.S.: already tried it without calling setupDragLabel and copied the code directly into "didMove"...this works fine...however this is just a way around the problem...so I would like to know why the way I am doing it at the moment doesnt work

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
let label1 = SKLabelNode()
let blueBin = SKSpriteNode()
let yellowBin = SKSpriteNode()

func setupDragLabel()
{

    //set font and label and position of the label
    label1.fontName = "Chalkduster";
    label1.fontSize = 20
    //label1.position = CGRectMake( 0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 10.0)

    //get a random number between 0 and 1

    let random = arc4random_uniform(2)

    //depending on the random number set the text and name to either blue or yellow

    if random == 0
    {
        label1.text = "blue"
        label1.name = "blue"
        }
    else
    {
    label1.text = "yellow"
    label1.name = "yellow"
    }
    // add the label to the scene
   addChild(label1)

    }
   override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    setupDragLabel()

    }
```

Comment: "It walways opens the debugger" and what does it say?

Answer (score 1):

### Maybe you have just a breakpoint enabled

In Xcode press <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> to open the *Breakpoint navigator*

[image]

If an entry is present (like in the image above) then a breakpoint is enabled.

In this case you can delete it or disabled it (just clicking on the blue arrow).

Finally run again your project, this time it will no longer stops.